# I need a specific format, from JavaScript Date object

Tags: javascript

I need exact date and time format like `12:48, Oct 30:`. How can I get this from current date or time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
let d = new Date();
const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June",
" July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
];

const d = new Date();
console.log(d.getHours() + ", " + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getDate());
```

You can change monthNames to suit your needs.